# How to define two multi-level headings styles in a same document?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have this kind of requirement

1. Heading 1

1.1 Heading 2

1.1.1 Heading 3

and at the end if you have appendix which needs following style

A. Heading 1

A.1 Heading 2

A.1.1 Heading 3

and subsequently appendix is like,

B. Heading 1

B.1 Heading 2

B.1.1 Heading 3

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The trick to this is to create a duplicate set of Styles. Base them on the equivalent Heading 1, 2, etc. but call them something like "Appendix H1", "Appendix H2", etc. or something similar.

Then apply a custom outline numbering scheme to the Appendix heading styles to match your requirement. Make sure that you link the outline level (in the custom numbering scheme dialog) to the new Style name.

In fact, re-reading your requirement. You may only need to copy the Heading 1 style.